# SQL Oracle Trigger to change date

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER shares_to_amount
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF issued ON shares_amount
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO shares_amount(
    share_issue_id,
    share_id,
    issued,
    date_start,
    date_end
  ) VALUES ( 
     :OLD.share_issue_id,
     :OLD.share_id,
     :NEW.issued,
     :NEW.date_start,
     :((NEW.date_start)-1).date_end
   );
END;
```

I want to change the `date_end` to the `date_new date -1` when a new share value is issued into 'issued'. The start date can be today's date but the end date will have to display the day before.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all your trigger can't work because of mutating table problem. You can't execute DMLs or queries in row-level triggers agains the table which is being changed by triggering DML (if the trigger is not autonomous but this is dangeros and exceptionac case). If I understand your question right you want to keep the history of changes made for shares. Th best way is to create PL/SQL package, incapsulate logic into procedures and provide this interface to end-users or other programms.

Comment: I just want to create a trigger which will replace the date_end to New date_start -1 when a new value is issued for issue.

Comment: >>will replace the date_end to New date_start -1 - OK, but in WHAT ROW ? Looking at your trigger I think you are trying to add the brand new record to the same table. This is impossible using trigger. Can you please clarify your requerements from the business point of view, not the technical one ?

Comment: I have a table shares_amount. It contains data share issued by company, its id, start and end date etc. What i want to do is to create a trigger which will update the shares_amount table before there is an insert on this table so that when a company declares a new amount of shares available, the currently listed valid entry has its end date set to the day before the start date of the new entry.

Comment: >>i want to do is to create a trigger which will update the >>shares_amount table before there is an insert on this table - as I said above the trigger is not the relevant way for this - please see Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm , section "Trigger Restrictions on Mutating Tables". PL/SQL interface gives you the ability to implement this logic plainly.